# Dispose pictureBox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I am using Winform in C++/CLI and I have `pictureBox1` and I am trying to compile the following code but it fails:

```
pictureBox1->Image->Dispose();
```

the compiler tells `Dispose is not a member of System::Drawing::Image` I tried to use it in C# and it works:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
```

I use MS Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: have you tried `delete pictureBox1->Image; pictureBox1->Image = nullptr;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please  try to do the following,

```
 delete pictureBox1->Image;   // Dispose the existing bitmap, if any
```